# SugarCRM Custom DetailView Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: textarea, sugarcrm, detailview

I have a text area that grows each week with date stamped data.  I want to know if it is possible to make it so that it stays at a certain size and has a vertical scroll bar, instead of having a huge text area.

Basically, I want it to look like it does in edit view, but not editable, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new file named **DetailView.tpl** in the **custom/include/SugarFields/Fields/Text/** directory ( which you may have to create ) with the following contents:

```
<span class="sugar_field" id="{{sugarvar key='name'}}" style="max-height: 200px;overflow: scroll; display: block;">
{{if empty($displayParams.textonly)}}
{{sugarvar key='value' htmlentitydecode='true'}}
{{else}}
{{sugarvar key='value'}}
{{/if}}
</span>
{{if !empty($displayParams.enableConnectors)}}
{if !empty({{sugarvar key='value'}})}
{{sugarvar_connector view='DetailView'}}
{/if}
{{/if}}
```

Afterwards, do a **Quick Rebuild and Repair** and that section should be limited to 200px high, and have scrollbars if the content gets longer than that.